# Hibernate Envers: Auditing an object, calling merge on it, gives an audit record EVERY time even with no change?

Tags: hibernate-envers

As in the title. I would expect Envers to only insert an audit record if the data has actually changed (have tried to help Envers along by providing equals and hashCode methods) - does this not come as standard?

Many thanks

Comment: It should. I assume everything is wrapped in a transaction? Which Hibernate version? What database?

Comment: Yes everything is wrapped in a transaction. MySQL database, Hibernate 4.2.2

Comment: Are you using InnoDB? (instead of MyISAM, which doesn't have transactions)

Comment: Yes, using innoDB, with transactional support

Comment: Could you update the post with your entity classes in question here and how you're able to trigger inserting the audit rows without changes?